# Username Failures When Connecting SQLAlchemy to MySQL

Tags: sqlalchemy, mysql-connector-python

I'm attempting to connect a python web application to a local database via SQLAlchemy.

I have configured the following connection string:

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@localhost:3306/db_mother
```

When I use the above, I get the following error (after a long stack trace):

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) None None

When I change the connection string to this:

```
sqlalchemy.url = mysql+mysqlconnector://ripley:amanda@localhost:3306/db_mother
```

I get an expected error, because that user is not configured with that password in the db:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ripley'@'localhost' (using password: YES) None None
```

So, in the first case I have a valid db user and password (which I can use to connect via command line or SequelPro), and it says I'm not using a password. In the second case it seems to understand that there is a password. Why does it not have this understanding in the first place?

I am using `python3`, `sqlalchemy`, `mysql-connector-python` and `pyramid`. It's also of note that if I strip the password from the root user, it works fine.